# Three.js raycasting and placing object above plane does not work

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I've created a plane based on a heightmap but intersecting it (raycasting) does not work.
Also i'm trying to place a object above the triangle i hover but this also fails

**EDIT: When you quote out the height (pgeo.vertices[i].z = heightmap[i] * 5;), it seems to work *SOMETIMES*. The highlight shows up but not always and it depends on the camera view also. If you zoom in/out the triangle disappears/appears again etc..**

I've based the jsfiddle on the voxelpainter example:

http://jsfiddle.net/waf6u7xp/1/

However i'm not sure if there is a better way to calculate which triangle i hover? Maybe with projection based on the heightmap? Any ideas?

this is the code that executes the raycast:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse2D.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse2D.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse2D.x, mouse2D.y, camera.near );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);

    // Toggle rotation bool for meshes that we clicked
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        var match = intersects[0];

        console.log(match);
        selectedTile = match.faceIndex;
        var f = face = match.face;
        var faceIdx = match.faceIndex;
        var faces = match.object.geometry.faces;
        var vertices = match.object.geometry.vertices;


        var fa = vertices[f.a];
        var fb = vertices[f.b];
        var fc = vertices[f.c];


        var a = fa.clone();
        var b = fb.clone();
        var c = fc.clone();

        highlightpla.geometry.vertices[0].setX(Math.ceil(a.x));
        highlightpla.geometry.vertices[0].setY(Math.ceil(a.y));
        highlightpla.geometry.vertices[0].setZ(a.z+1);
        highlightpla.geometry.vertices[1].setX(Math.ceil(b.x));
        highlightpla.geometry.vertices[1].setY(Math.ceil(b.y));
        highlightpla.geometry.vertices[1].setZ(b.z+1);
        highlightpla.geometry.vertices[2].setX(Math.ceil(c.x));
        highlightpla.geometry.vertices[2].setY(Math.ceil(c.y));
        highlightpla.geometry.vertices[2].setZ(c.z+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: That jsfiddle is using three.js r54 which is pretty old. I've updated it with the latest stable (r68). http://jsfiddle.net/waf6u7xp/3/

Comment: @mrdoob thanks didn't notice i accidentally included the old one. Anyways this really seems like a bug! Once the height is applied it   doesn't detect intersections at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fooled around some time to locate your problem, but I found it :)

Your code is totally working except for one thing. The problem is that the heightmap array has only 2493 points. This means your point geometry is way out of range with a dimension of `127 x 127`

If you change your PlaneGeometry to a valid amount of `widthSegments` and  `heightSegments` for the amount of points it is totally working.

So change code to:

```
var size = Math.floor( Math.sqrt( heightmap.length ) ) - 1;
var pgeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 16384/2, 16384/2, size, size );
```

And all is okay...

[Here is an updated and cleaned up fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waf6u7xp/7/)

Comment: Thank you for your time however, i still don't see the blue hovering triangle?

Comment: Edit: i still don't ALWAYS see the blue hovering triangle? It fails most of the time, i'm running at 60fps so i don't know what is going on :(

Comment: You also have to set/clone your normals to the matching face.

Comment: i've added:

        highlightpla.geometry.faces[0].normal.setX(f.normal.x);
        highlightpla.geometry.faces[0].normal.setY(f.normal.y);
        highlightpla.geometry.faces[0].normal.setZ(f.normal.z);

but this doesn't change anything?

Comment: Thank you very much, i see it works now, but you are just replacing the face right? That is perfect solution if you only need to triangle. But my goal was to highlight the square of which the highlighted triangle (which i raycasted) is a half of. So i thought i could calculate the 4th point using the 3 points of the triangle and set the vertexes manually like i did in my code, or isn't that the right way to do it?

Comment: Anyways i've made a second highlight plane which now covers the other half, however i feel like it's not the right way to do it. Couldn't i use something like projection ,and based on the heightmap that i've, find which 2D square (x,y) i'm hovering? And than i store the square vertexes based on (x,y) of the square so i can easily highlight it?

Comment: Oh well i'll just dig into the source code and if i don't find i'll create a new post. (However feel free to answer if you know) Thanks!

Comment: @CaptainObvious That you can do easily like this: http://jsfiddle.net/waf6u7xp/8/

Comment: Thanks again, you've been a great help!